# Dynamic CSS Javascript Function Failing (Possibly Due to Hyphens)

Tags: javascript, css

I am struggling with getting this function written correctly. I think it's likely due to the hyphens, but what do I need to fix. I'm pretty fresh at this all.

```
<script>
  window.onload = logoSwap;
  function logoSwap() {
  var ispodcast = document.getElementsByClassName('Header-branding-logo')[0]; 
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('podcast') > -1) {
    ispodcast.style.["backgroundImage"] = "url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ef4dab726e12c6968e8d01a/t/5f037e0d221f791c5b93cedc/1594064397866/dtw_logo_podcast_icon_wht_v1.svg')";
  } else {
    ispodcast.style.["backgroundImage"] = "url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ef4dab726e12c6968e8d01a/t/5f037e08fd93f51aabeae9a9/1594064392428/dtw_logo_guide_icon_wht_v1.svg"";
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I would use document.queryselector('.Header-branding-logo') to make it more clear. But beside that `/dtw_logo_guide_icon_wht_v1.svg"";` <-- The double " is not correct.

Comment: When you do JS stuff you can just open the browser console - normally you see errors there in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot before the square brackets. Either use bracket notation or dot notation to access properties; do not try to combine both. You also used two double quotes together instead of a single quote before the double quote in the else branch.

```
  if (window.location.search.indexOf('podcast') > -1) {
    ispodcast.style["backgroundImage"] = "url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ef4dab726e12c6968e8d01a/t/5f037e0d221f791c5b93cedc/1594064397866/dtw_logo_podcast_icon_wht_v1.svg')";
  } else {
    ispodcast.style["backgroundImage"] = "url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5ef4dab726e12c6968e8d01a/t/5f037e08fd93f51aabeae9a9/1594064392428/dtw_logo_guide_icon_wht_v1.svg')";
  }
```

Comment: @SamuelAyres No problem.